# Offline speech recognition on Windows in python 3

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I've been trying to make an offline speech recognizing program which works on Windows.  https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/
Neither of the engine/API supports mentioned on this page have both of the following conditions:
1) Works on Windows
2) Works offline

I've searched a lot on different occasions and finally it seems to me that there are no engines which can be trusted to make a speech recognizer in python 3 on Windows. Any help?

Comment: No, Microsoft kills them because that would hurt their profits ;) The free alternative is Linux.

Comment: How come... So you're saying there is no absolute way to use a library to make a speech recognition program without using the internet on winOS?! I thought it was so rare because windows isn't comfortable with these fast processing speech processing code written in C or something.. but you say it's with their profit. Strange.

Comment: Can you please share your findings with us?

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are still struggling-
I recommend using `vosk` offline speech recognition package for python

their website - [vosk docs](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/)